# Command Line Prompt Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, command-line, command, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I'm hoping someone can help.

In the first image, you can see that the directory command (ie: dir) shows that the file `vbc helloworld.vb` is definitely in the source folder.

[image]

In the second image, you can see that the file cannot be found when I try to run `vbc helloworld.vb`, even though the path is correct.

[image]

Can anyone let me know what is going wrong?

I also know the vb.exe is in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`

I added that to the PATH in This PC Environmental Variables, but that didn't do anything at all.

Actually, I have no idea what to do now.

Also, I want to use Visual Studio Command line without using Visual Studio itself. I know it's easier to use Visual Studio Module itself, and that using the command line is old fashioned, but I still want to learn how to use the Command prompt with vb.Net.

Hope you can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your filename shouldn't contain the command vbc.

Rename your file from "vbc helloworld.vb" to helloworld.vb, and then run: vbc helloworld.vb

Comment: I have done that and the command then says:                           Microsoft (R) Visual Basic Compiler version 2.8.2.62916 (2ad4aabc) Copywrite (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.       But there is no "Hello World" showing as it should do. I welcome any help you can give.

Comment: @Confused Is there now a "helloworld.exe" program in that directory? vbc compiles the source code into an executable program.

Comment: @Confused Try running helloworld.exe by typing helloworld and pressing enter.

Comment: Success!!!!! Oh my goodness Peter. I did what you suggested on a couple of ocassions before I wrote in for help. BUT, I didn't even think to type in helloworld and pushing enter as the next step. That was the step I was missing. Big thanks to you Peter. Now I know how to continue on. Andrew, there is a hello.exe in the Directory, as I'm sure you have guessed from my lack of knowledge reflected in this comment. Lots to learn :)) Thanks guys.